# Music Education in the UK: skipping all grades?

Tags: piano, teaching, education, exam-grades

I live and work in the UK as an engineer. In the past, aroudn 10 years ago, I got a diploma in piano with 10/10 cum laude in an Italian Conservatory. After a hiatus of several years, I started playing the piano again recently, and I would like to move my career again in that direction (maybe teaching, etc).

I think I would have a better shot in a music career here in the UK (or in Europe) if I have an UK title such as LRSM, without having to explain everytime how does it work in italy. 
My technique is at a good level. I think that in around 8 months I could be ready for the LRSM in the UK. However, I cannot take the LRSM if I don't have the DipARSM, and I cannot do that if I don't have the Grade 8.

I would be happy to take DipARSM, but the Grade from 1 to 8 are way too easy for me, and would simply be a waste of time and money for me to do it. So the question: is it possible to skip them in order to take LRSM? Alternatively, is it possible to do directly one exam for Grade 8 in order to get the Grade 8 qualification?

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Having diplomas in UK is not necessarily a prerequisite, unless you are working in some institutions. Privately,  more people are not going to ask. And, in any case, having diplomas doesn't particularly make you a good, or  sought after teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth having a read of the syllabus on the ABRSM web site.  There are alternative qualifications they accept, and they may accept appropriate and documented experience.

Alternatively, do grade 8 theory, then grade 8 in any instruments you want.  Then apply for the diploma.  You don't have to do all the exams up to grade 8, but you will need grade 5 or above in theory to do the performance exams.

Comment: So I can do Grade 5 theory, Grade 8 exam, and then start with DipABRSM and so on?

Comment: That seems to be what the requirements say.  No specific grade requirement in music theory.  But if you want to teach, you might be better going for grade 8 theory.

Answer (score 1):

When I was 'doing grades' some 50 years ago, There was no requirement to complete all of them in order.  The higher grades had Grade V theory as a prerequisite, apart from that, you could jump straight in at Grade VIII.   I don't think it's changed since then.

Comment: Different institutions have different requirements about the theory exam.

Comment: On piano, I believe all boards require gradeV theory to continue beyond with practical. For the OP ABRSM would do the trick, within several months, for theory V and grade VIII practical.